# How to quickly calculate large factorials by hand

Tags: factorial

How would I calculate something like 30! by hand? Is it necessarily tedious? Or are there some techniques to make it faster and easier?

Comment: Depends on what form you want it in. You can pretty easily do the prime factorization for example.

Comment: There are approximations to calculate factorials, like the Stirling approximation and Ramanujan's factorial approximation.

Comment: Do you want the exact value, or is an approximation sufficient?  Do you have log tables at hand?